# Can inductance ever vary with current?

Tags: induction, inductance, electromagnetic-induction

Question is just as above. My thought is that since resistance of a material can vary with current (in a non-Ohmic conducter), is it possible for inductance $L$ in an inductor to vary for different amounts of current? In other words, is the induced electromotive force always equal to $-L\frac{dI}{dt}$?

Comment: [Josephson junctions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephson_effect) have inductance that depends on current.

Comment: Hint: for inductors made with with permeable cores, the [magnetization curve of the core is non-linear](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a7/Magnetization_curves.svg)

Comment: In theory, components behave ideally. In reality, well, not so much (but usually not all that much if using within specified limits). Even V = IR is not perfect, since the resistor dissipates energy, so the temperature changes, which may change the resistivity.

Comment: @DanielSank:"Josephson junctions have inductance that depends on current."- Yeah, but that's not a "real inductance". It's not storing energy in a magnetic field. You can say that operationally it can behave in a circuit like a "real inductance", but if that is going to be the definition of an inductor then one could also build an electronic circuit in a black box which to an outside observer behaves like an inductor that has an inductance which varies with current.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoricaly, from Maxwell equations, the *emf* can't be distinct of $-\dfrac{d \Phi}{dt}= -L \dfrac{d I}{dt}$. But in fact, an apparently constant quantity can vary a little for any conditions, I mean, experimentally you can see what happens to inductance $L$ with respect the time, current, temperature or whatever ($L(I, T, t, ...)$) and maybe you see something extrange in few of many attempts, but statistically, L is constant.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at hysteresis, the property of ferromagnetic materials to have permeabilities dependent on the previous magnetic field which had passed through the material. As the field generated by wires is affected by current, then any material capable of exhibiting hysteresis will be affected by currents present and past.

To my limited knowledge!